# using a .bsc (source browser) file with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am facing an issue with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 premium edition. As an interface its brilliant! That is not my problem :-)

In my team, we use VS2003 as a debugger and code editor. Our code base is however, not inside a Visual Studio project or solution. It can never be due to the nature of our product. The typical way we use the product is to start our application, attach the process to the VS debugger and open our source files. Until now, we had a bsc file (source browse information) to enable source code browsing. This bsc file is created using our custom gmake script which uses the VS2003 compiler. For some reason, the support for bsc files seems to be withdrawn from VS2010. It works in VS2008. There is also an MSDN discussion on this topic:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/98c94456-05dc-4958-9f5a-2982070b07da

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Our project is using a 3rd party open source library primary developed for the UNIX environment.  It comes with its own makefiles, autoconfig scripts etc and cannot be directly added to a VC++ project.  I am considering downgrading to VS2008 for using the bsc files that come with the library.

Answer (score 0):

A VS project seems to be needed (even a dummy one) for .bsc file to work. Create a (dummy) project, add to it the browser information file, the (available) source and header files it's built from.

I've tried it on both VS Express 2010 and 2013.